# PHP Define index for HTML form $_POST

Tags: php

I have the following php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) OR !isset($_POST['address_building_number'])){
        $address_building_number = $_POST['address_building_number'];
        echo 'Hello';
        $good = 'Good bye';
    }
    echo $address_building_number;
    echo $good;

?>
```

When I hit the submit button the words Hello and Good bye are displayed but it is telling me   *PHP Notice:  Undefined index:* Now `$_POST['address_building_number'` is from an HTML input form with a name address_building_number.

How can I modify `if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) OR !isset($_POST['address_building_number'])){` so that I can 'define the index' while be still able to echo Hello and Good bye.

Comment: Your conditionals seem to be fighting against themselves. What you probably meant to use is `if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) OR !empty($_POST['address_building_number']))` - And if that's the case, `||` has precedence over `OR` so use `if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) || !empty($_POST['address_building_number']))`

Comment: And, is your form input named? I.e.: `<input type="text" name="address_building_number">` - If not, then that's the problem. Use `var_dump($_POST['address_building_number']);` to see if anything comes up or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

#### All-in-one version

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) || !empty($_POST['address_building_number'])){
        $address_building_number = $_POST['address_building_number'];
        echo 'Hello';
        $good = 'Good bye';
    }
    echo $address_building_number;
    echo $good;

    // comment out exit; if you want the form to NOT appear after submit
    // exit;
?>

<form action="" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="address_building_number"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

## Original answer

Your conditionals seem to be fighting against themselves.

Notice the `if(isset` and `if(!isset` for the `$_POST['address_building_number']`

What is happening here is, "if it **IS** set and if it is **NOT** set"; being a contradictory statement.

What you probably meant to use was:

```
if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) OR !empty($_POST['address_building_number']))
```

(Quick FYI) If that's the case, `||` has precedence over `OR` therefore use:

```
if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) || !empty($_POST['address_building_number']))
```

...which checks to see if it is set, and if it is not empty.

The following has been successfully tested and echo'ed everything with no error messages:

**HTML**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="address_building_number"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP** (action.php) for example

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['address_building_number']) || !empty($_POST['address_building_number'])){
        $address_building_number = $_POST['address_building_number'];
        echo 'Hello';
        $good = 'Good bye';
    }
    echo $address_building_number;
    echo $good;
?>
```

In regards to *"so that I can 'define the index' while be still able to echo Hello and Good bye"* - I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by this.

If what you mean by this is, "if you can still echo "Hello and Good bye" outside of that conditional statement", then the answer is yes; which is just what my answer does, since it's using the `OR` (`||`) operator. Had it been the `AND` (`&&`) operator, then that would not be possible.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it is still giving me errors I used these _Name: <input type="text" name="address_building_number"><br>_

Comment: Hi, I think I solved it by creating an external file...before the HTML form and the PHP file were in the same file. Now I created user.php which contains the HTML form and action.php which processes user.php

Comment: You didn't mention that your HTML form and PHP were inside the same file. My codes were using an example external filename of `action.php` but that can be anything you want it to be. @user3173207 If you feel the question can be closed now, please accept my answer as being correct. I can make up another version with everything included in one file. See my **Edit**.

Comment: Hi, how can I modify your code to keep it in the same file please without giving me the errors it was giving me? Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome. It's in my **Edit All-in-one version** reload the page to see it. Pre-tested ;-) @user3173207 - which I did an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

1st - your if statement is wrong it always results in true. I am not sure what you trying to do here?

2nd - PHP Notice: Undefined index is shown because your if statement is always true even if you have submitted form or not.

3rd - maybe change if loop to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Also make sure submit button has `name="submit"`